# working samples for using cordova media plugin to play sound in intel xdk

Tags: android, audio

Can anybody please recommend a working example for using cordova media plugin in intel xdk environment to play sound on android phones? I tried this example (http://qnimate.com/create-a-music-player-app-using-intel-xdk/) without luck. The code for that sample is attached. I tried html5 audio tag and Soundjs library but they don't play sound on android native browser. Some online posts suggest the cordova media plugin would be a fix for android browser. However, I googled a lot and still cannot find a working example. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--
    * Please see the included README.md file for license terms and conditions.
    -->
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <style>
        @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }                          
        @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
        @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }                                    
        @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
    </style>

<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
     <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('http://labs.qnimate.com/sound.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>        
<script src="cordova.js"></script>      
<script src="xhr.js"></script>              
<script src="js/cordova-init.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
<script src="js/init-dev.js"></script>
<script>
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //http://labs.qnimate.com/sound.mp3
        playAudio("http://labs.qnimate.com/sound.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player

    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        if (my_media == null) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
        } // else play current audio
        // Play audio. playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked make sure the audio is playing even if screen is locked.
        my_media.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : true });

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    //
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    //
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    //
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

</script>       
</body>
</html>
```